# Converting between timezones seems to still use the timezone of the machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm writing a function for my discord bot which takes two inputs, time in hours and in what timezone it is (boiled down to "us" and "eu"). It can only convert between Stockholm and Chicago. I thought I was setting the time with these:

```
var stockholm = new moment({
  hour: args[1], // 15
  minute: 0,
  second: 0,
  millisecond: 0,
}).tz("Europe/Stockholm");

console.log(stockholm); // Moment<2021-02-06T15:00:00+01:00>

var chicago = new moment({
  hour: args[1], // 15
  minute: 0,
  second: 0,
  millisecond: 0,
}).tz("America/Chicago");

console.log(chicago); // Moment<2021-02-06T08:00:00-06:00>
```

If I'm thinking about this right I'd like the chicago one to output `Moment<2021-02-06T15:00:00-06:00>`.

Here's the function I use to convert one of the above into another timezone:

```
function zone(mo, newTimeZone) {
  console.log(moment(mo).tz(newTimeZone));
  return (time = moment(mo).tz(newTimeZone).format("hh:mm z"));
}
```

Which is done in this switch depending on the input of the user.

```
switch (args[0]) {
  case "us":
    const time = zone(chicago, "Europe/Stockholm");
    break;

  case "eu":
    const time = zone(stockholm, "America/Chicago");
    break;
}
```

This code works for converting from stockholm to chicago but not the other way around. I'm guessing it is because the chicago variable is not set correctly and that might be because my local timezone corresponds to the stockholm one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the `mo` format but you should using the format time for `mo` in moment() as argument like this:

```
function zone(mo, newTimeZone) {
  console.log(moment(mo, "HH:mm:ss").tz(newTimeZone));
  return (time = moment(mo, "HH:mm:ss").tz(newTimeZone).format("hh:mm z"));
}
```